# Apache camel is sending zero size files to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am currently using apache camel to send files to S3 bucket using S3 Component.

```
from(S3_ENDPOINT).setHeader(S3Constants.KEY, header(FILE_PATH))
.setHeader(S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH,header(FILE_LENGTH)).to(s3EndpointSettings.getURI()).setHeader(STATUS,constant(FILE_BACKED_UP_IN_S3_MESSAGE)).to(STATUS_PROCESSOR).routeId("s3_route").end();
```

But, sometimes camel push 0 size files to S3.
I suspect that, Camel is not able to retrieve file length correctly, which needed to be set as "S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH".

If that is the case, then is there any other way we can resolve this issue?

Comment: The header S3Constants.CONTENT_LENGTH gets its value from header(FILE_LENGTH). Print the headers via ${headers} before setting headers to see what value FILE_LENGTH has.